# App crashing - was accepted into app store

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, report

I've updated my app from iOS5/iPhone 4 to iOS6/iPhone5 compatible. The app was approved by the apple store and is available to download, when downloaded from the app store it crashes on start-up. However, installing the app from xcode onto devices works perfectly, I'm at a loss. I've attached a link for the crash report

any help would be most appreciated

http://pastebin.com/epgh2Jxv

Comment: Have you changed CoreData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the app from your device completely, clean the product, then run again from xcode.  I bet the problem comes out on yours too.  It seems that a storyboard doesn't exist.  You probably removed it by mistake but it is still existing cached in your product since Xcode doesn't actively go searching for old files to delete.